# Tags "replayer" and "pgn-viewer"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Should these two tags from the *meta* site: [replayer](/questions/tagged/replayer) and [pgn-viewer](/questions/tagged/pgn-viewer) be synonimized?

Comment: Which one should be the parent tag? I'll synonymize them once we (as a community) pick a parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I synonymized the tags so now [replayer](/questions/tagged/replayer) is a synonym for [pgn-viewer](/questions/tagged/pgn-viewer).

Answer (score 5):

I find the term "replayer" to be rather confusing, so I think [replayer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replayer) should be synonimized to  [pgn-viewer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgn-viewer).